# How to construct a flipped single bit bitfields with an index?

Tags: go

What's the most efficient way to construct a flipped single bit bitfields given an input index?

For example:

```
input: 0 output: 100000000000
input: 1 output: 010000000000
input: 2 output: 001000000000
input: 9 output: 000000000100
```

Comment: You mean like `1 << index`?

Comment: How do I convert that to bitfield?

Comment: what do you mean by bitfield?

Comment: I think you want something like right shift 1 >> index

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [right shift operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators), which shifts each bit in its left operand to the right as many times as specified by the right operand.

```
x >> y // Shifts each bit in "x" to the right "y" times.
```

To display bitfields as in your example you'll want to use a left operand with only the leftmost bit set, then shift right the number of times as given, and use the `%b` printf directive to get a binary string, for example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/KaNHgY3LAr1)):

```
func setbit16(idx uint8) string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("%016b", uint16(0x8000)>>idx)
}

func main() {
  xs := []uint8{0, 1, 2, 9, 15, 20}
  for _, x := range xs {
    fmt.Printf("%2d -> %q\n", x, setbit16(x))
  }
  //  0 -> "1000000000000000"
  //  1 -> "0100000000000000"
  //  2 -> "0010000000000000"
  //  9 -> "0000000001000000"
  // 15 -> "0000000000000001"
  // 20 -> "0000000000000000"
}
```

Of course, if you just want the resulting number and not necessarily to display the bitfield then you can just use the operator (or the left shift version):

```
uint16(0x8000) >> 2 // => 0b0010000000000000
uint16(0x0001) << 2 // => 0b0000000000000100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  What if the max length is 4194304 and I want the output to be []byte?